# integrating validation for numeric input into the rest of the code

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms, validation

I am using this code to validate postcodes. the code works like a charm but I would like to validate the input before submission and make sure the input is numeric ONLY. I added this to the code :

**Code1- Code for validating numeric input**

```
 function validateForm() {
     var x = document.forms["form2"]["postal"].value;
     if(/[^0-9]+$/.test(x)) {
         alert("The postcode must have ONLY numeric characters - Please go to contact page if you live outside Australia.");
         myformName.myformField.focus();
         return false;
     }
 }
```

but unfortunately it doesn't work. Is there anyone who can help me with this? I would like to know how the above code can be integrate into code in below:

**code2 - the main code**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#tab-container').easytabs();
});
var xmlHttp;

function check() {
    xmlHttp = GetXmlHttpObject();
    if(xmlHttp == null) {
        alert("Browser does not support HTTP Request");
        return;
    }
    var code = document.getElementById("postal").value;
    document.getElementById("loader4").style.visibility = 'visible';
    var url = "Ajax/check_code.php";
    url = url + "?p=" + code;
    //alert(code);
    xmlHttp.onreadystatechange = stateChanged;
    xmlHttp.open("GET", url, true);
    xmlHttp.send(null);

    function stateChanged() {
        if(xmlHttp.readyState == 4 || xmlHttp.readyState == "complete") {
            //alert(xmlHttp.responseText);
            if(xmlHttp.responseText == 1) {
                //alert(xmlHttp.responseText);
                //document.getElementById("pro").disabled = false; 
                window.location.href = 'booking.html';
            } else if(xmlHttp.responseText == 0) {
                document.getElementById("results").style.visibility = 'visible';
                document.getElementById("results").innerHTML = 'Alert Message';
            }
            document.getElementById("loader4").style.visibility = 'hidden';
        }
    }
}

function GetXmlHttpObject() {
    var xmlHttp = null;
    try {
        // Firefox, Opera 8.0+, Safari
        xmlHttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    } catch(e) {
        //Internet Explorer
        try {
            xmlHttp = new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP");
        } catch(e) {
            xmlHttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
        }
    }
    return xmlHttp;
}
```

and here is HTML:

```
<form name="form2" onsubmit="return validateForm();">
    <label>STEP 1:</label>
    <label>Enter Your Post Code</label>
    <input type="text" name="postal" placeholder="e.g. 4000" id="postal"  />
    <input type="button" class="call-to-action" name="pro" id="pro" onclick="check()" value="Book Now" />
</form>
```

so again I would like to add code1 in the code2 and get the numeric validation works.

Comment: in what way doesn't it work? are you getting an error in your console?

Comment: Hi @arnorhs no there is no error. it sounds like the added code doesn't even exist..

Comment: Is your validate form method being called? The way I'd go about debugging this is to add a console.log() at the top of the validation function and seeing if it's getting called or not.. if it is, then i try to see what the value of the form field is using console.log as well.. if the value is right, then i'd look at the regular expression.

Comment: Is there a reason you are not using jQuery selectors and AJAX functions when you already have jQuery loaded?

Comment: @itsmejodie no reason. just don't know a better way. the postcodes are checked server side. Are you saying I should do the numeric validation server side as well?

Comment: @arnorhs I added console.log() on top of the validation code but nothing happened. I wasn't sure how to do the regular expression though.

Comment: @MohammadMoezzi you can do AJAX validation first before you do server side validation, but I am suggesting that if you are using the jQuery library, then you should learn some of the jQuery functions that make doing this kind of thing a lot easier [$.get()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get/) [jQuery Selectors](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/basic-css-selectors/)

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example of your code which binds a click handler to the `pro` button, and first checks that the `postcode` is a 4 digit number before submitting an AJAX request (via `$.get()` to your `Ajax/check_code.php` handler. I've added an `id` to your `<form>` tag, and your button to accommodate this.

HTML:

```
<div id="results"></div>
<form id="form2" name="form2" action="booking.html">
    <label>STEP 1:</label>
      <label>Enter Your Post Code</label>
      <input type="text" name="postal" placeholder="e.g. 4000" id="postal"  />
      <input type="button" class="call-to-action" name="pro" id="pro"  value="Book Now" />
</form>
```

Javascript using jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    //$('#tab-container').easytabs();
    $('#pro').on('click', function() {
        $('#results').hide();
        var $postal = $('input[name="postal"]');
        if (!/^[0-9]{4}$/.test($postal.val())) {
            alert("The postcode must have ONLY numeric characters - Please go to contact page if you live outside Australia.");
            $postal.focus();
            return false;
        }
        $.get('Ajax/check_code.php', {p: $postal.val()}, function(data) {
            if (data == 0) {
                // data = 0
                $('#results').html('Alert Message').show();
                return false;
            }

        });
    });
});
```

Here's a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6Tm8H/)

Comment: you code is shorter and cleaner however the input is not checked by the server side file. the loader also doesn't show up. The page also doesn't redirect to book.html page when I input a right post code.